# Accessing class static member using QMetaType

Tags: c++, qt, static, member, qmetatype

I am using `QMetaType::create` to instantiate some of my objects and would like to be able to access a static member of the class before doing so, is it possible to do that with `QMetaType` ?

Comment: What do you mean by accessing it? If it's static and you have the type, then you can, yes. If you don't have the type, then no, you can't, C++ is a statically typed language.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher i have the `typeId` that can be used with `QMetaType`

Comment: So no, not possible, that's not a type.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher ok thanks

Comment: [This thread](https://forum.qt.io/topic/64446/calling-static-function-through-qmetaobject/9) from 2016 says no. `moc` just does not generate the metadata/code for the purpose. If you need this, you gotta code it yourself (switch-case or typeId-lambda dictionary or whatever).